# Time difference of given timestamp

Tags: perl

I want to calculate time diff of below time stamp on windows .

tt1= 2013/08/16 23:59:59:785

tt2 = 2013/08/16 23:59:59:753

and outut should be : 000826.288000

i have tried below code but getting output as 16799588.000000 .

But output should be like 000826.288000 .Please help me to get correct time stamp 000826.288000.

```
use DateTime::Format::Strptime;
my $dp = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
  pattern => '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S:%3N'
);

# Create two DateTime objects
my $tt1 = $dp->parse_datetime('2013/08/16 23:59:59:753');
my $tt2 = $dp->parse_datetime('2013/08/16 23:59:59:785');

# The difference is a DateTime::Duration object
my $diff1 = $tt2 - $tt1;
#print " t1 and t2 are : $diff $tt1 and $tt2 \n";

my $diff = sprintf "%013.6f", $tt2 - $tt1;
```

Answer (score 3):

The difference between your timestamps is 32 milliseconds, no matter how you format them, you won't get `000826.288000` as a result. Assuming you got a proper Duration result:

```
use DateTime::Duration qw();
use DateTime::Format::Duration qw();

print DateTime::Format::Duration
    ->new(pattern => '%06S.%06N')
    ->format_duration(
        DateTime::Duration->new(seconds => 826, nanoseconds => 288000000)
    );
__END__
000826.288000
```